# Python three dimensional array of zeros w/out using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Create three dimensional array of zeros without the usage of numpy library or any external libraries or packages.
Similar format to that of the output of

```py
import numpy as np
np.zeros((10, 10, 4))
```

But not using numpy

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: This might be a bit brute force but I would suggest using nested loops to iterate through each entry into the multi dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension can be used to create arrays of zeros of any dimension you like.

1D: `[0 for i in range(4)]`

2D: `[[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(10)]`

3D: `[[[0 for i in range(4)] for j in range(10)] for k in range(10)]`